# Conflicted with foreign key

Tags: c#

I want to delete a record from sql server using C# but it didn't work. The error          message reads as follows

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Waskat_table_User_table". The conflict occurred in database "Tailor_db", table "dbo.Waskat_table",column 'Uid'.  The statement has been terminated.

```
{
    Sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommond("DELETE FROM User_table WHERE ID ="+txtid.text,con);
    Sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommond("DELETE FROM Waskat_table WHERE ID ="+txtid.text,con);
}
```

Comment: you should do a google search on the error also look here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776269/i-got-error-the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint

Comment: Try deleting the Id from `Waskat_table` first and then from the `User_table`. Reverse the deleting sequence and see if that helps. I am just a beginner so I might be wrong

Comment: You should read about SQL injection and how to avoid it. http://bobby-tables.com/csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you are trying to delete, its exists into another table as foreign key. So, until you delete child foreign key from that table you can't delete mother table data. You can also adjust your foreign key as ON DELETE NO ACTION.

There are more at [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976689/do-i-need-to-specify-on-delete-no-action-on-my-foreign-key) and you can know more from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql)